# Include Relationships when creating profile

Tags: custom-fields, profile, relationships

i was wondering if there's an easy way to add the relationship field when creating a profile.

what i wish to accomplish is this:

1. perform a search for all members of a particular household, plus a few more criteria---easy enough to do.
2. display the result as:
   | Name | Email | Phone | Member of (household) | Some contact specific custom field |

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to do this if you are using Drupal and that would involve the Webform+CiviCRM module. Happy to explain more if you are on Drupal - but you don't mention your CMS

Comment: thanks! the setup is drupal 7 + Civi. i was aso thinking along Webforms and Civicrm. i just thought there's an easier way for the end user. anyways, i should have looked a bit deeper. i found the Extended reports extension (https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports) sufficiently handles the requirements.

Comment: I am sorry. I should have read your question more slowly. I saw 'profile' and just assumed you meant you were using it for collecting info, not displaying it. I should delete my answer and you should add your own ;-)